# Post request in python not working on remote server

Tags: flask, python-requests

I have to make a post request, It is working fine on localhost. 
Following is code to upload file

```
 data = {'id': id}
 with open(file_url, 'r') as some_file:
            files = {'some_file': some_file}
            url = remote_server + '/api/save'
            res = requests.post(url, files=files, data=data)
```

following is code on server

```
 parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument('id', type=str, required=True, help="Required argument id")
        parser.add_argument('some_file', type=werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage, location='files')
```

On remote server it is not getting parameters. It is showing help message

```
Required argument id
```